# Activating the dropout in model eval mode in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, dropout

```
def eval_with_dropout(self):
        self.eval()
        for module in self.modules():
            if isinstance(module, nn.Dropout):
                module.train()
```

is it possible this way of implementing `dropout ensemble` in pytorch for model evaluation would mess other things in pytorch? is it the correct way of implementing `dropout ensemble`?

as I know the only differences in model.train() and model.eval() are in activation of `Dropout layers` and `Batch normalization layers`, but I am not sure about messing other components or procedures of training and evaluating in pytorch